# Event config page suddenly not working

Tags: civievent, javascript

This evening, I was working on adding a few custom fields to a profile we're using for an event.  Finished up, tested, all was well.  I went to take my test registration off the event and check that the right staff were copied on the notification and instead, I'm getting screens that look like this:
[image]

Errors look like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?  I have torn out most of my hair now.  I'm also a javascript idiot, so be gentle.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who might have this same snafu, this was what happened:

1. Asset caching had been enabled in **Debugging and Error Handling**  I usually set this as disabled, but we have been working on website speed for a while, so I enabled it.  For two weeks, I had no problem with it.
2. BUT the uploaded image files resource url which is usually [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/dyn  is set to go somewhere outside of civi.

With the asset caching set, it was looking for js and css files in [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/dyn, which is where it would store those for caching.  This meant NO menu as the crm-menu related things would be stored there.  I have no idea why I didn't have this problem sooner.

However, there was also a little piece of javascript in a formatting field in the profile I was using for this event, which caused the screens and errors above.

So, two unrelated errors, I think.  An extra two hours troubleshooting.  And, as always with me, it was a PICNIC error (Problem in chair, not in computer). Hopefully, my late night troubleshooting will help someone else.